# Update my state but cant update my UI in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I get the value (true/false) from my function messageArrived(this function get value from mqtt topic) then I update the state, but my view element does not update its state (does not switch). What am I doing wrong? How can I change the state of an element?
I tried to call the event in the messageArrived method, but it did not help, the element was not redrawn as I needed

MyUIState

```
data class StoveScreenUiState(
val turn: Boolean = false,)
```

MyEvent

```
sealed class StoveFormEvent {
data class TurnStoveChange(val turn: Boolean): StoveFormEvent()}
```

MyViewModel

```
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(StoveScreenUiState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()
fun onEvent(event: StoveFormEvent) {
        when(event){
            is StoveFormEvent.TurnStoveChange -> {
                turnStove(event.turn)
                setBoolean(5,event.turn)
            }
}

    private fun turnStove(turn: Boolean) {
        _state.update {
            state.value.copy(turn = turn)
        }
    }
    override fun messageArrived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) {
        _state.update {
            state.value.copy(turn = message.toString().toBoolean())
        }
    }

}
```

MyStoveScreen

```
fun StoveScreen() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<StoveScreenViewModel>()
    val state = viewModel.state.collectAsState().value
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        gradientStart,
                        gradientEnd
                    )
                )
            )
            .padding(20.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            NormalTextComponent(value = "Плита")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
            Row (
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ){
                StoveCard(size = 0.45f, text = "Включение", value = state.turn, onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(StoveFormEvent.TurnStoveChange(turn = it))
                })
           }
    }
}
```

```
fun StoveCard(size: Float, text: String, value: Boolean, onValueChange: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(size)
            .height(120.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(8.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = gradientEnd)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(9.dp))
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(CenterHorizontally),
                text = text,
                color = Color.White
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier
                .height(20.dp)
                .width(150.dp))
            Divider(modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .paddingFrom(FirstBaseline, 0.sp),
                thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.White)
            Switch(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End),
                checked = value,
                onCheckedChange = onValueChange,
                colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                    checkedThumbColor = gradientEnd,
                    uncheckedThumbColor = gradientEnd,
                    checkedTrackColor = Color.White
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippit taken from your one with only switch function. I have tested it in my PC it working check it.

**Screen**

```
@Composable
fun Stack08(stack08ViewModel: Stack08ViewModel) {
    val viewModel = viewModel<Stack08ViewModel>()
    val state = viewModel.state.collectAsState().value

    Column {
        Button(onClick = { stack08ViewModel.onEvent(StoveFormEvent.FakeApiCall(!state.turn)) }) {
            Text(text = "Fake Api Call")
        }
        StoveCard(value = state.turn) {
            stack08ViewModel.onEvent(StoveFormEvent.TurnStoveChange(!state.turn))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun StoveCard(value: Boolean, onValueChange: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Column {
        Switch(
            checked = value,
            onCheckedChange = onValueChange,
        )
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class Stack08ViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(StoveScreenUiState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    fun onEvent(event: StoveFormEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is StoveFormEvent.TurnStoveChange -> {
                turnStove(event.turn)
            }
            is StoveFormEvent.FakeApiCall -> {
                fakeApiCall()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fakeApiCall() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(5000)
            _state.value = state.value.copy(turn = true)
        }
    }

    private fun turnStove(turn: Boolean) {
        _state.value = state.value.copy(turn = turn)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the switch itself works. But it doesn’t work if I change the state from the outside (let’s say I receive it via API, or in this case, like in my messageArrived() function, which sends (true/false) via mqtt)
In this case, the element is not toggled.

Comment: Okay, Got it I'll give you that example

Comment: Check out updated answer here I have made a function which delay for 5 second to mimic API call and then update the Switch State.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main language and I probably explained it wrong. The essence of the problem is that I have my function messageArrived(topic: String, message: MgttMessage) I receive a message from there every time someone sends a message to the mqtt topic from the outside. This is a message from true or false. I probably need to update the state in the messageArrived function depending on what value comes. And so that my switch changes automatically as soon as the state changes. Without pressing additional buttons.

Comment: You need to add other logic ```messageArrived``` to update it automatically using ```Flow``` or other way

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `val state = viewModel.state.collectAsState().value` with `val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()`

Comment: It did not help